# VS 2017 starts chrome with black screen

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Sometimes when I execute my asp.net core project the visual studio 2017 starts a new chrome window but with black screen.

I use my chrome normally, not have this problem.

I would like debug my javascript code inside IDE.

How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me disabling hardware acceleration in chrome helps.
To do that you can simply open Chrome settings page and:

1. Click on **"Show advanced settings link"**
2. At the very bottom, in the section **"System"**, uncheck **"Use hardware acceleration when available"**